# Regex to extract data from ipconfig using existing data

Tags: regex, parsing, regex-lookarounds

I have the following regex that extracts the Key Value Pairs which works well.  I receive this data via another system from a number of machines already and I would prefer to use the data I have already rather than use WMI to get the data again.

```
(^.*?)[^\w]+\:\s(.*?$|\n\r)$
```

Question - 1 - I would like to be able to also extract the adapter name with a separate regex. Could you assist with this

Question - 2 - The regex that I have does not pick up lists of values. e.g. The list of DNS Suffix Search List OR the list of DNS Servers.

My source data is below. Any assistance is appreciated

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : abcmyhost
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : parker.industries
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid-GLS
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : YES
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : YES
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : parker1.industries
                                       parker2.industries
                                       parker3.industries
                                       parker4.industries
                                       parker5.industries
                                       parker6.industries
                                       parker7.industries
                                       parker8.industries
                                       parker9.industries
                                       parker10.industries

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 5:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : parker.industries
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Ready 2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 60-11-11-31-09-XY
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : NO
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : AB80::11FG:1KI:LK9F:12N2%19(Preferred) 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 111.222.333.444(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Monday, November 11, 2019 6:23:03 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Wednesday, November 13, 2019 6:51:30 AM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 111.11.131.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 111.22.144.199
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 87244642462
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-02-03-04-05-06-07-08-09-10-11-E9-G7
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 111.22.111.254 
                                       111.22.112.254
                                       111.33.113.254
                                       111.33.114.254
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Comment: What if the system has more than one adapter?

Comment: And what is the main purpose of this? I may help with a better solution, but as a sysadmin I guess too many possibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can make use of the `\G` anchor to get repeating matches to get for example the list for `DNS Suffix Search List` , you might use:

```
(?:(^[^:\r\n]+):?[\r\n]+|\G(?!^))\r?\n[^:\r\n]+ : ([^\r\n]+(?:\r?\n(?!.* : )[ \t]+[^\r\n]+)*)
```

In parts

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `(` capture **group 1**
  - `^[^:\r\n]+` Match 1+ times any char except `:` or newline from the start of string
  - `)` Close group 1
  - `:?[\r\n]+` Match optional `:` and match 1+ newlines
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert position at the end of previous match, not at the start
- `)` close non capturing group
- `\r?\n[^:\r\n]+` Match a newline, then match 1+ times any char except `:` or newline
- `:`  Match space, `:` and space
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `[^\r\n]+` Match 1+ times any char except a newline
  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `\r?\n` Match a newline
    - `(?!.* : )` Assert that the next line does not contain  `:`
    - `[ \t]+[^\r\n]+` Match 1+ spaces or tabs and 1+ times any char except a newline
  - `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times
- `)` Close group 2

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/chlMpr/1)

Comment: Thank you, the solution has worked well for me.  The \G was really useful and will make use of it for future solutions.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit complicated, but you can likely simplify that,

`(?i)^\s{3,}(DNS[^.:]*)[^:\r\n]*:\s*(?:(?:[a-z0-9]*\.[a-z0-9]*[\r\n]\s{10,})+[a-z0-9]*\.[a-z0-9]*)|(?:(?:(?:\d+\.){3}\d+)\s*)+(?:(?:\d+\.){3}\d+)|^\s{3,}(?:[^.:]*)[^:\r\n]*:\s*(.*)$|^([^:]+):$|^(.*)$`

I wasn't sure how the other samples may look like.

The key to write such expressions is alternation. We would first pick the most complex pattern, and continue towards the simple ones (similar to FizzBuzz).

Here, our most complex pattern is the one with multi-lines. After collecting that, simpler lines remain.

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/KL9SqZ/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/KL9SqZ/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Happy 20k rep (:

Answer (score 0):

Answer to question #1:

```
/adapter (.*):/
```

will simply do, assuming different types of adapters (Ethernet, Wireless, etc.).

You may also get the type adding another `(.*)`

```
(.*) adapter (.*):/
```